# Determine VMWare type from within VM

Tags: linux, vmware

Is it possible to determine VMWare type (ESXi, Workstation, Fusion, ...) from within the VM (i.e. guest OS) itself, provided guest VM is a Linux machine?

I've tried various things, such as grepping for `hypervisor` in `/proc/cpuinfo`, using `lscpu`, etc. but all I found is it's "vmware", no specifics.

I don't have root privileges on the machine, if that changes things, though I'd be interested in solutions that are possible with root only, that will be handy for some things. Also I'm mostly interested in Linux solutions, but again Windows-only solutions may come in handy.

The reason I'm asking is to be able to figure out the performance. ESXi is a) usually deployed on "real hardware"™ and b) does not have additional OS overhead. See [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/242143/relative-performance-of-vmware-player-workstation-server-and-esx) for more details, especially [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/242163).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this information?

Comment: Try this command `vmware -vl` it didn't specify if this was to be done on the host OS or guest OS, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: @DrZoo OP did specify: "from within the VM (i.e. guest OS)"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm talking about the command I gave. The knowledge base didn't specify if that command is to be run from inside the host OS or guest OS. Point being, if you run it in the guest OS, it's possible the command will not be found.

Comment: @DrZoo Ahhh  gotcha... :)

Comment: @Ramhound For performance reasons. http://serverfault.com/questions/242143/relative-performance-of-vmware-player-workstation-server-and-esx

Comment: @DrZoo Hm... I don't have that command in guest OS, might be a host-only command?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The one that you linked is for Windows guests. I also do not see how it explains the way you figure out whether it's e.g. ESXi or Workstation.

Comment: You might consider changing your question on how to tell if a virtual machine is compatible with a type 1 hypervisor or not, it seems to me, that is actually what you are truly after.  Your question is as-is is still very confusing.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - In simple terms, I'm asking how from VM guest to see if it's ESXi, so that I know it's a better hypervisor. Can you clarify what's confusing, so I can edit the question?  I also don't see what you mean by "if a virtual machine is compatible with a type 1 hypervisor" - I thought from guest VM perspective it doesn't matter, i.e. that you can have the same guest VM on type 1 or type 2 hypervisor (or even convert between these).

Comment: ESXi is a type 1 hypervisor, any other VMware product would be a type 2 hypervisor, and you are correct, they are compatible.  Which is the reason your question is confusing.  VMWare virtual machines are compatible with VMWare products, so which product created the virtual machine, would not really be kept in a file except perhaps the configuration but only the schema version ( 12,11,6,5.5,ect.)

Comment: @Ramhound Let's continue over chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35828/determine-vmware-type-from-within-vm?tab=general

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the version from the BIOS version strings in the dmidecode output. I found one example of how to do this at https://fritshoogland.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/determine-vmware-esx-version-from-linux-as-guest-os/ which dates back to 2013, so it's probably missing some newer versions:

```
case $( dmidecode | grep -A4 "BIOS Information" | grep Address | awk '{ print $2 }' ) in
"0xE8480" ) echo "ESX 2.5" ;;
"0xE7C70" ) echo "ESX 3.0" ;;
"0xE7910" ) echo "ESX 3.5" ;;
"0xE7910" ) echo "ESX 4"   ;;
"0xEA550" ) echo "ESX 4U1" ;;
"0xEA2E0" ) echo "ESX 4.1" ;;
"0xE72C0" ) echo "ESXi 5"   ;;
"0xEA0C0" ) echo "ESXi 5.1" ;;
"0xEA050" ) echo "ESXi 5.5" ;;
* ) echo "Unknown version: "
dmidecode | grep -A4 "BIOS Information" 
;;
esac
```

Our ops team couldn't tell me which version of ESX we were running a few years back (ugh!!), but I needed to know because we were gearing up to test a new product which required a specific version of the hypervisor.  This worked like a champ for me.

If you need to do this as a non-root account, use sudo.  Use 'visudo' to access the sudoers file, then add a line similar to below near the end of the file:

username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dmidecode

This will allow 'username' to access dmidecode without any special authentication, just run "sudo dmidecode" rather than "dmidecode".

Comment: Thanks Jeff - this is useful when you have root permissions. Any way to do it without root?

Comment: Add your non-root user to sudoers file with permission to execute dmidecode as root without a password.

Comment: Updated my answer to include sudo instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess what I wanted to ask - if you cannot get root / sudo permissions, is there a way to get the same or similar information?